# Why is that a non-holomorphic mapping $f:M\to N$ between compact complex manifolds indicates $\bar{\partial} f$ has only finite zeros?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

suppose $f:M \to N$ is a non-holomorphic mapping between compact complex manifolds, and $\partial \bar{f}:T^{1,0}M \to T^{0,1}N$ is a tangent map locally written as
$$ \partial\bar{f}= \dfrac{\partial \bar{f}^j}{\partial z^i} dz^i \otimes \dfrac{\partial }{\partial \bar{w}^j}  $$

where $\{z^i\},\{w^j\}$ are local frames of $M,N$ respectively. Now assume $f$ is not holomorphic, why $\partial\bar{f}$ has finite zeros?

Edit: I read this from the proof of the following:

Any stable harmonic map from $S^2$ to a compact K"{a}hler manifold with positive holomorphic bisectional curvature is holomorphic or anti-holomorphic.

In *Geometry of Harmonic Maps* written by Xin Yuanlong, page 104.

While the author assume the map is neither holomorphic nor anti-holomorphic, then both $\partial f$ and $\partial\bar{f}$ have finite zeros.

I can get this through, how?

Comment: Can you please add information to the question about where this comes from? Is it a question you made up and believe to be true? Is it a textbook exercise? Did it arise in the course of asking some question about holomorphic mappings and your considerations led you here? That kind of thing....

Comment: I added it in, do you have a clue about it?

Comment: This is certainly not true as written.  I would guess there are much stronger assumptions in the context in which this was stated that you have omitted.

Comment: didn't see any sign of stronger assumptions in the context of the question. All the formulas work for the stability of the map and the positive curvature condition, only this conclusion comes directly from the non-holomorphicity of the map in order to tell the energy integral (exclude the zero set) is positive. Am I missing something?

Comment: For example, if the mapping $f$ is _harmonic_, that would qualify as what Eric rightly terms a _much stronger assumption_.